# EF Core incapsulation in Unit Of Work pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, ef-core-2.0, ddd-repositories

I've got problems with joining DDD and EF Core.

I'm making project using DDD architecture. As Data Access level I use generic Unit of Work pattern taken from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/770156/Understanding-Repository-and-Unit-of-Work-Pattern).

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<TDomain> Repository<TDomain>() where TDomain : class;
}

public interface IRepository<TDomain>
{
    TDomain Get(Expression<Func<TDomain, bool>> predicate);
}
```

Realizing these interfaces I use EF Core.

I've got some domain model with 2 classes

```
public class MainClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<RelatedItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class RelatedItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MainClass Parent { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In real life of my project `MainClass` has collection with hundreds of `RelatedItems`. In order to perform some operations I need only one `RelatedItem` per request with some date. It can be done by searching through `Items` property.

Incapsulating perfomance of EF Core in unit of work I have to load explicitly entities from DB with related items, because business login layer doesn't know anything about realization of UnitOfWork's repository. But this operation is very slow.

So I decided to create `MainClassService` which injects in costructor `unitOfWork` and have method which returns only one `RelatedItem`, and it works fine.

```
public class MainClassService
{
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public MainClassService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    public RelatedItem GetRelatedItemByDate(int mainClassId, DateTime date)
    {
        return unitOfWork.Repository<RelatedItem>().Get(c => c.Parent.Id == mainClassId && c.Date == date);
    }
}
```

So I've got situation when I cannot use property `Items` directly because of EF Core, but I should use them because of DDD architecture.

**And my question is: is it ok to use such a construction?**

Comment: It is a bit unclear of what you are asking. Are you asking if it is ok to inject `unitOfWork` into `MainClassService` or are you asking which conceptual model you should follow (EF Core vs DDD methodologies)? If the latter, in DDD your domain objects should be persistence ignorant. Don't let EF dictate how you interact with you domain objects. Rather, make EF (or other DAL code like your repositories) accommodate your DDD architecture.

Comment: What are the business rules that made you to create those two domain model classes?

Comment: @bman7716 you're right, I'm interested in the latter.

Comment: @Constantin Galbenu It was just an example. One agregate with big collection of related entities

Comment: @Timothy related or nested?

Comment: @Timothy the design is very strongly dependent on the business rules/invariants.

Comment: @Constantin Galbenu nested. Sorry for my english

Comment: @Timothy in DDD one must load the entire Aggregate in order to mutate it. Lazy loading in this case is not an option, nor infrastructure services injected into entities. You can however split the models (write from read); see CQRS.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu thanx for CQRS link! According to this methodology my MainClassService can be used as the query, isn't it?

Comment: @Timothy yes, it can be used only for reading. However, this implies that it should return *readonly/immutable* representations of RelatedItem

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu thanx! You helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it seems from your question, the `MainClass` is an Aggregate root and `RelatedItem` is a nested entity. This design decision should be based on the business rules/invariants that must be protected. When an Aggregate needs to mutate, it must be fully loaded from the repository, that is, the Aggregate root and all its nested entities and value object must be in memory before it execute the mutating command, no matter how big it is.

Also, it is not a good practice to inject infrastructure services into Aggregates (or in nested entities). If you need to do this, then you must think again on your architecture.

So, from what I wrote you can see that the problem manifest itself only when you try to mutate the Aggregate. If you only need to read it or find it, you could create some dedicated services that find the data using infrastructure components. Your `MainClassService` seems to be such a case, where you need only to read/find some `RelatedItem` entities.

In order to be clear that the purpose is only reading, the `MainClassService` needs to return a readonly representation of the `RelatedItem` entities.

So, you just madee some first steps towards [CQRS](http://cqrs.nu/), where the models are split into two: READ model and WRITE model.

Comment: @Timothy Be more specific please. A command is just a plain object, it cannot call anything.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie in this terms. Can execute method in CommandHandler call Queries? Doesn't it contradicts to CQRS approach?

Comment: @Timothy You can call query services but without breaking Domain Driven Design. Also, you need to take into account that those query services return stale data (eventually consistent data). So, you are *allowed* to call query services for example when you do lookups: suppose that you have the command `ActivateUser(userId)` but you have only the `userEmail`, you can lookup the user's ID by email before executing the command. Anyway, the details depends a lot on your programming language/used framework/etc.

Comment: what do you mean "without breaking  DDD"?

Comment: @Timothy DDD (Domain Driven Design) comes with some "rules" regarding the Aggregates. One of them is to not modify more than one Aggregate per transaction. I was referring in general, to try to not model long running business processes in the command handler because server can restart and leave your system in an inconsistent state.